# SAS- how to do ASCENDING order when concatenating

Tags: sorting, sas

How do you sort the values by ascending order when concatenating for SAS?

eg. In this example I am trying to acsend values for aeacnoth1_std1, aeacnoth2_std, etc.....

```
if cmiss( aeacnoth1_std, aeacnoth2_std)=0 
    then aeacolst=strip(aeacnoth1_std)||','||strip(aeacnoth2_std);
 if cmiss( aeacnoth1_std, aeacnoth2_std, aeacnoth3_std)=0 
    then aeacolst=strip(aeacnoth1_std)||','||strip(aeacnoth2_std)||','||strip(aeacnoth3_std);
 if cmiss( aeacnoth1_std, aeacnoth2_std, aeacnoth3_std, aeacnoth4_std)=0 
    then aeacolst=strip(aeacnoth1_std)||','||strip(aeacnoth2_std)||','||strip(aeacnoth3_std)||','||strip(aeacnoth4_std);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

1. Declare an array containing all the variables you want to concatenate
2. Sort the array into the desired order
3. Concatenate the array

The hard part is step 2, as SAS 9.1 or earlier doesn't provide any direct way of doing this. You might find this paper useful, or just Google for 'sas sort array' and see what comes up:

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p096-26.pdf

EDIT: if you have SAS 9.2 or later, you can use `call sortc` to sort the array:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003106052.htm

Comment: thanks! that was helpful. This is what I ended up:

    `do i=1 to 4;
        do j=1 to 4-i;
            if sort(j) > sort(j+1) > . then do;
                temp=sort(j);
                sort(j)=sort(j+1);
                sort(j+1)=temp;
            end;
        end;
     end;`

Comment: If you're satisfied with this answer, please could you upvote it and mark the question as closed? It's how this site works.